# Dynamics365 web api update vs upsert

Tags: dynamics-crm, microsoft-dynamics-webapi

I'm quite confused. I understand the actual difference between those two, but I can't see any difference in the actual implementation here.

Here is an excerpt from the docs

### [Basic update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/update-delete-entities-using-web-api#basic-update)

> Update operations use the HTTP `PATCH` verb. Pass a JSON object
>   containing the properties you want to update to the URI that
>   represents the entity. A response with a status of 204 will be
>   returned if the update is successful.
>
> This example updates an existing account record with the accountid
>   value of 00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001.
>
> ```
> PATCH [Organization URI]/api/data/v9.0/accounts(00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000001) HTTP/1.1  
> Content-Type: application/json  
> OData-MaxVersion: 4.0  
> OData-Version: 4.0  
>
> {  
>     "name": "Updated Sample Account ",  
>     "creditonhold": true,  
>     "address1_latitude": 47.639583,  
>     "description": "This is the updated description of the sample account",  
>     "revenue": 6000000,  
>     "accountcategorycode": 2  
> }
> ```

### [Upsert](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/update-delete-entities-using-web-api#upsert-an-entity)

> An upsert operation is exactly like an update. It uses a `PATCH`
>   request and uses a URI to reference a specific entity. The difference
>   is that if the entity doesn’t exist it will be created. If it already
>   exists, it will be updated. Normally when creating a new entity you
>   will let the system assign a unique identifier. This is a best
>   practice. But if you need to create a record with a specific id value,
>   an upsert operation provides a way to do this. This can be valuable in
>   situation where you are synchronizing data in different systems.
>
> Sometimes there are situations where you want to perform an upsert,
>   but you want to prevent one of the potential default actions: either
>   create or update. You can accomplish this through the addition of
>   `If-Match` or `If-None-Match` headers. For more information, see [Limit
>   upsert operations](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamics365/customer-engagement/developer/webapi/perform-conditional-operations-using-web-api#bkmk_limitUpsertOperations).

So in reality `Basic update` as stated above will be an `upsert` and to achieve a real basic update (update if given account eixists, 404 otherwise) I need to add the `If-Match: *` header to the `PATCH` request.

Did I understand that correctly?

Answer (score 1):

I have the same understanding here as you have.  In practice, I've found that using a patch request without `If-Match: *` will do an insert if the record doesn't exist.  The puzzling piece however, is that when the upsert succeeds in inserting a record, it returns a `404` error.  When I've included the `If-Match: *`, I've received a `400` error when the update failed.